# Case with few conditions in one row

Tags: sql, oracle

NEW EDIT !

I would like to get  something like that:

```
ID1     DATE_1       DATE_2        DATE_3 
---     -------      -------       -------
99999 | 12-08-2016 | 14-08-2016 |  17-09-2016
```

but I get:

```
ID1     DATE_1     DATE_2      DATE_3
----    ------     --------    --------
99999 | 12-08-2016|           |
99999 |           | 14-08-2016|   
99999 |           |           | 17-09-2016
```

That my code:

```
create table TABE1 as
select  
      A.ID1,
      max(CASE 
         WHEN A.ID2 IN (123,1234,12345,123456)  THEN A.CONATACTDATE
      END) AS DATA_1,

      max(CASE 
         WHEN A.ID2 IN (456,4567,45678,456789)  THEN A.CONATACTDATE
      END) AS DATA_2,

      max(CASE 
         WHEN A.ID2 IN (987,9876,98765,987654)  THEN A.CONATACTDATE
      END) AS DATA_3,   

      max(CASE 
         WHEN B.ID3 IN (1,2,3,4) THEN B.ID3
      END) AS ID_CC, 

      max(CASE 
         WHEN B.ID3 IN (1,2,3,4) THEN B.ID3
      END) AS ID_WW,

      max(CASE 
         WHEN B.ID3 IN (6,7,8,9) THEN B.ID3
      END) AS ID_CC2, 

      max(CASE 
         WHEN B.ID3 IN (6,7,8,9) THEN B.ID3
      END) AS ID_WW2
      from DATABASE1 A  LEFT JOIN 
      (SELECT ID1, ID2, ID3, FROM DATABASE2) B
      ON A.ID1=B.ID1
      WHERE A.ID2 IN (123,1234,12345,123456,456,4567,45678,456789,987,9876,98765,987654) 
      group by A.ID1,A.CONATACTDATE,B.ID3
```

ID1 is person ID, ID2 is contact ID with this person (everyone is contact at least once and maximum three times)

I will be grateful for help!

Comment: Do a GROUP BY. (Or self left joins)

Comment: Add group by A.ID1

Comment: I wouldn't think that this information will be important: It was only a portion of all code, there is another table which I join: from database1 A join database2 B on A.id1=B.id1. So how to use group by in this condition ?

Comment: at the end add Group By A.ID1

Comment: with this group by i get: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Comment: you should set all CASE in MAX and you should include all other fields in the GROUP BY

Comment: I still get one person three times.

Comment: Show us the statement

Comment: This statement cannot be the whole statement. See "ID_WW2, FROM" and "ID3, FROM "

Comment: My mistake, I have to rename columns so by accidant I wrote comma, I don't get a error, I get the same results what without goup by and max

Comment: Because B.ID3 has nothing to do in the group by. It is in the case. And you dont need CONATACTDATE in the group by

Comment: I didn't understand  "you should include all other fields in the GROUP BY " .Now everything is good! THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: Which you use and by which you want to group by. Thank @JPG not me.

Answer (score 2):

Use `group by` and `max` can achieve that:

```
....       
       A.id1, 
       Max(CASE 
             WHEN A.id2 IN ( 123, 1234, 12345, 123456 ) THEN A.contactdate 
           END) AS DATE_1, 
       Max(CASE 
             WHEN A.id2 IN ( 456, 4567, 45678, 456789 ) THEN A.contactdate 
           END) AS DATA_2, 
       Max(CASE 
             WHEN a.Id2 (987, 9876, 98765, 987654) THEN A.contactdate 
           END) AS DATA_3 
FROM   database1 A 
JOIN some table or something else
GROUP  BY A.id1 -- this is the last line.
```

Comment: I wouldn't think that this information will be important: It was only a portion of all code, there is another table which I join: from database1 A join database2 B on A.id1=B.id1.  So how to use group by in this condition ?  Sorry about my English !

Comment: @A.Kier `GROUP  BY A.id1` and wrap `case when` clause with `max`.

Comment: I get statement: "This is not the expression group by" (or something like that, I translate this from my language) near this which came from a second table (database2)

Comment: @A.Kier Updated my answer, please check.

Answer (score 0):

You can never get such output(as per your conditions):

Here it is with example:
As you are using `ID2` in case statement. As in a single row `ID2` can have only one value. So if the value is in `(123,1234,12345,123456)` then only your first `case` statement gets a hit, the other two case statements fail so `DATE_2` and  `DATE_3` are set to `NULL`, resulting in something like.

```
ID1    ///   DATE_1   ///    DATE_2     ///   DATE_3

99999  ///12-08-2016
```

In simple words only your case statement's were written in such a way only one would get hit and other two would return NULL for any row